# juju Kubernetes Core setup not starting after reboot on Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to setup a Kubernetes system on a server (48 cores and 65 GB ram). I figured conjure-up/juju would be the way to go and it installs the services and starts them, but when I restart the server only some of the services comes up again, the others are stuck in a waiting state.

Why are the services not starting up, the "Message" section gives a few different messages each time I reboot. The dump beneath is after the server has been up for at least 12 hours so it does not seem to fix this by it self.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ juju status
Model                        Controller                Cloud/Region         Version
conjure-kubernetes-core-da5  conjure-up-localhost-989  localhost/localhost  2.1.3

App                Version  Status   Scale  Charm              Store       Rev  OS      Notes
easyrsa            3.0.1    active       1  easyrsa            jujucharms    9  ubuntu  
etcd               2.3.8    active       1  etcd               jujucharms   34  ubuntu  
flannel            0.7.0    waiting      2  flannel            jujucharms   15  ubuntu  
kubernetes-master  1.6.2    waiting      1  kubernetes-master  jujucharms   19  ubuntu  exposed
kubernetes-worker  1.6.2    active       1  kubernetes-worker  jujucharms   23  ubuntu  exposed

Unit                  Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports           Message
easyrsa/0*            active    idle   0        10.0.8.11                       Certificate Authority connected.
etcd/0*               active    idle   1        10.0.8.69       2379/tcp        Errored with 0 known peers
kubernetes-master/0*  waiting   idle   2        10.0.8.131      6443/tcp        Waiting to retry addon deployment
  flannel/0           waiting   idle            10.0.8.131                      Waiting for Flannel
kubernetes-worker/0*  active    idle   3        10.0.8.115      80/tcp,443/tcp  Kubernetes worker running.
  flannel/1*          waiting   idle            10.0.8.115                      Waiting for Flannel

Machine  State    DNS         Inst id        Series  AZ
0        started  10.0.8.11   juju-36585e-0  xenial  
1        started  10.0.8.69   juju-36585e-1  xenial  
2        started  10.0.8.131  juju-36585e-2  xenial  
3        started  10.0.8.115  juju-36585e-3  xenial  

Relation      Provides           Consumes           Type
certificates  easyrsa            etcd               regular
certificates  easyrsa            kubernetes-master  regular
certificates  easyrsa            kubernetes-worker  regular
cluster       etcd               etcd               peer
etcd          etcd               flannel            regular
etcd          etcd               kubernetes-master  regular
cni           flannel            kubernetes-master  regular
cni           flannel            kubernetes-worker  regular
cni           kubernetes-master  flannel            subordinate
kube-control  kubernetes-master  kubernetes-worker  regular
cni           kubernetes-worker  flannel            subordinate
```

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: No, I started looking into CoreOS woth Docker Swarm mode instead but have no clear solution for Kubernetes (which I would prefer) there either. This seem like such a basic thing to have working, I don't see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `etcd` crashes on boot, and `snapd` fails loading some dependency. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/juju-solutions/bundle-canonical-kubernetes/issues/357#issuecomment-316542831) recommends doing the following:

```
juju run --application etcd 'service snap.etcd.etcd restart'
juju run --application kubernetes-master 'service snap.kube-apiserver.daemon restart'
juju run --application kubernetes-master 'service snap.kube-controller-manager.daemon restart'
juju run --application kubernetes-master 'service snap.kube-scheduler.daemon restart'
juju run --application kubernetes-worker 'service snap.kubelet.daemon restart'
juju run --application kubernetes-worker 'service snap.kube-proxy.daemon restart'
```

This worked for me using both the base Kubernetes charm and the "Canonical" variant.

Comment: Thanks, these kind of things could have made it work I think. I still have the kubernetes-master/0 in Workload "waiting" with Message "Waiting to retry addon deployment" for over about an hour after restart. I'll try to look into the logs a bit more.

Comment: @Tirithen the rest of it is likely caused by LXD. [Here is a GitHub issue](https://github.com/juju-solutions/bundle-canonical-kubernetes/issues/357#issuecomment-320742789) where I outline how I fixed it. Let me know if it worked. I will do my best to push on them to get this added to the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I started purging/re-installing lxd/lxc as well as conjure-up/juju and it got a bit messy, I'll report back once they are back to stable.